# Setting up IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for Scala/SBT

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I' ve been struggling with setting up IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for use with Scala/SBT for the past couple of hours and currently i am facing an error that i dont even know how to look up properly. Googleing the error code didnt help unfortunately :(.

So, everytime i set up a new project or import an existing one, following the instructions found here:

https://scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started-intellij-track/building-a-scala-project-with-intellij-and-sbt.html

and

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html

i am getting the following error msg as soon as the project has finished loading:

Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...

```
[error]   at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
```

[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
Invalid response.
See complete log in file:/home/a0947188/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log

I have properly installed SBT 1.0.3 and the scala plugin 2.1.14.

Do you have any idea what i can do about this? I need to hand in the project in 2 weeks and our teacher specifically requires us to use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Lorenz, are you sure the project builds with plain `sbt`? This log looks like you just have some dependency (library jar) that can't be resolved. Show us your `build.sbt` or wherever you put your dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorenz I had exactly the same problem. 
When reading the whole error message i found https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j where sbt seems to search for an update, but it is not available.

My solution was, to use older SBT and Scala plugins:
I'm now using SBT 0.13.13 and Scala 2.12.0 and everything is working fine so far. (JDK version should be 1.8)

I hope it will work for you too.